# Multiple GWT Session parallel in the same Browser

Tags: session, gwt, spring-security, smartgwt, browser-tab

We have a SmartGWT application (with Spring security) for which we want the same user to be able to login 
with the same login info but get different session for different tabs.

1. User 1 opens a browser tab Tab1 with the application

   - gets a session Session1
   - chooses a role ...
2. User 2 opens a browser a new Tab2 with the application

   - gets a new session Session2

   User uses the Tab1 and Tab2 in parallel. The session should not influence each others.

Our current application uses spring security. It would probably be no problem to have role based 
GrantedAuthorities for the user. But we would rather have complete different sessions in order to
simplify the code of the application.

A Cookie based session system does not seems to be possible, without invalidating the session.
But the session should not be invalidated... Only a new session should be attached to the new tab.

HttpSession.getSession(true) only returns a new session  if none exists.

It seems to be possible to use an URL rewriting approach in order to create a new session. 
1 Could anyone tell us whether it is possible and

1a if yes, give us an idea of the implementation issues
or steps.

One aspect I am not completely sure  what consequences there are if one uses the URL Rewriting method.

2 Does that mean that if the client send a request without session id that a new session is created

3 Does the url rewriting aspect have other consequences for the GWT backend

Answer (score 1):

Since there is just one session that can be attached to a browser and a website, the only way I can possibly think about is to have different sub-domains for each tab, that will force new sessions to be created (at that point also a new login, so an openid login would be handy).

What I mean is having, for instance www.yourdomain.com in tab 1, www2.yourdomain.com in tab 2, www3.yourdomain.com in tab 3 and so on up to a reasonable max number of tabs.

Alternatively, if possible, it would be much simpler to educate the users to have 2 or 3 different browsers (for instance Firefox, Opera, Chrome, Safari, to mention the good ones).

Comment: This seems to be the case if the session is stored with cookies. But how is it if you disable session cookies?

Comment: If you disable session cookies, or the user doesn't accept cookies, you have to make sure that the URL doesn't contain the JSESSIONID parameter, when you load the content for a new tab.